# Set and get the active page in angular2-datatable

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2.  Currently I have a table that is being implemented using angular2-datatable -> DataTableModule.

My codes in displaying the table is shown below:

```
    <table id="questionList" class="table table-striped" [mfData]="_question.questionList" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5" 
        [mfActivePage]="activePage" (onPageChange)="onPageChange($event)">
        <thead>      
            ......
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ......
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

In my .ts file I have a variable "activePage: number = 2" So I am expecting that the 2nd tab in my data list will be shown.  But sadly it didn't work.  Evertime I run the program, it always shows the 1st 5 items instead of the 6 - 10 items in my table.

And I want as well to keep track on the last activePage that is being visited. So I put (mfOnPageChange)="onPageChange($event)." But the code in my .ts file is never called.

```
onPageChange(event) {
  console.log("ON page change");
  this.activePage = event.activePage;
}
```

SO, what is really the best way to set and get the activePage in angular2-datatable -> DataTableModule.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using (click) method of mfBootstrapPaginator instead of using onPageChanges() in table

```
<table id="questionList" class="table table-striped" [mfData]="_question.questionList" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5" 
    [mfActivePage]="activePage" >
    <thead>      
        ......
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ......
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]" (click)="onPageChange(mf)"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Be sure that your loop is over mf.data

```
<tr *ngFor="#item of mf.data">
```

There are a [plunk working](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/TY5IO5) here